# Multiprocessing Queues with python

Tags: python, queue, multiprocessing, pool

I am attempting to create a basic script to make use of multiprocessing to work through a queue full of objects and call a method on each one.

I understand the principles of multiprocessing and pools etc. Please see below what i have done:

```
from multiprocessing import Queue, Pool
from object import obj
import time

currentTime = time.time() #used to work out how long it takes for the script to complete

work_queue = Queue()

#create some objects to work with
a = obj('obj1')
b = obj('obj2')

#put them in the queue
work_queue.put(a)
work_queue.put(b)

def doFunction(q):
    temp = q.get()
    print temp.getVar()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(2) #Create a pool with two processes
    pool.map(doFunction, work_queue, 1)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

print time.time() - currentTime #prints out the time taken to run script
```

This throws an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/adam/workspace/MultiProcessing/test2.py", line 35, in <module>
    pool.map(doSNMP, work_queue, 1)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 251, in map
    return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 304, in map_async
    iterable = list(iterable)
TypeError: 'Queue' object is not iterable
```

If anyone could provide any input i would be most grateful!

Comment: Probably you need to read the multiprocessing document.  the `map()` method takes the tasks that you want to process such as `[a, b]`.

Comment: It looks like you want `apply`, not `map`.

Comment: Helpful link https://pymotw.com/2/multiprocessing/communication.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Error: Queue is not iterable

The error trace is very clear on the problem. It was even surprise to me, but Queue is really not iterable.

## Modified test code

`Queue` is mostly used to communicate items between processes. But your code simply took something to do and read some property from it, so there is not much to communicate about.

For that reason I have modified your code.

- Object class defined in the code
- work_queue replaced by something iterable, in this case it is a generator, able producing any number of items of type `Object`.

Use of `pool.map` is left. It generates tasks to do from iterable.

```
from multiprocessing import Queue, Pool
import time

class Obj(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def getVar(self):
        return self.name


currentTime = time.time() #used to work out how long it takes for the script to complete

def jobgenerator(num):
    for i in xrange(1, num+1):
        yield Obj("obj"+str(i))

def doFunction(job):
    time.sleep(1)
    print job.getVar()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(2) #Create a pool with two processes
    pool.map(doFunction, jobgenerator(10), 2)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

print time.time() - currentTime #prints out the time taken to run script
```